# -bash: doc2dash: command not found in OS X Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, bash, terminal, pip

I have a two day old Mac Pro with OS X Mavericks and need to get [doc2dash](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/doc2dash) working.

I've installed Python, pip and doc2dash, but I keep getting the following error when typing "doc2dash" in Terminal.

```
-bash: doc2dash: command not found
```

Here is what my `.bash_profile` file looks like:

```
# Set architecture flags
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
# Ensure user-installed binaries take precedence
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# Load .bashrc if it exists
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc


#[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

#[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

##
# Your previous /Users/USERNAME/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/USERNAME/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2014-03-08_at_02:37:54
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-03-08_at_02:37:54: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
#export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

Edited based on comments:

> which doc2dash

Returns nothing.

When I run 'sudo pip install --user doc2dash', the following appears:

> ```
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): doc2dash in /Users/USERNAME/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
> Cleaning up...
> ```

When I list the doc2dash files in the directory above, this is what appears:

```
drwxr-xr-x   9 USERNAME  staff  306 Mar  8 02:28 doc2dash
drwxr-xr-x   9 USERNAME  staff  306 Mar  8 02:28 doc2dash-1.2.0.dist-info
```

doc2dash does not reside in /usr/local/bin.

Can someone please tell me what to do in order to get this command to work?

Comment: How did you install `doc2dash`, and where was it installed? If in `/usr/local/bin`, does `/usr/local/bin/doc2dahs` run the program? What does `which doc2dash` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip install --user` installs commands to `~/Library/Python/2.7/bin`. Update your `.bash_profile` to include the line:

```
export PATH="$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Then open a new terminal and the shell will be able to find `doc2dash`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Can't believe how much time I wasted trying to get this to work!!