# Install Frappe Framework - bench: command not found

Tags: python, git, bash, installation, pip

I am new to python and Frappe framework. I followed the steps provided in the following link to install Frappe framework on my Mac OS Sierra.

[Frappe Bench Github](https://github.com/frappe/bench)

After successfully installing Python, MariaDB, Node JS, Redis and wkhtmltopdf (with patched qt) I created new folder named "FrappeSample" and run the following commands in it:

```
git clone https://github.com/frappe/bench bench-repo

pip install --user -e bench-repo
```

Now when I try to run the following command to install frappe bench

```
bench init frappe-bench && cd frappe-bench
```

I get the error which says:

> -bash: bench: command not found

Can anyone please guide me what I did wrong or is there any extra configuration needed which was not properly mentioned in the documentation ?

Comment: What does Qt have to do with your problem?

Comment: I am getting the same message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-bash: doc2dash: command not found in OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271232/bash-doc2dash-command-not-found-in-os-x-mavericks)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524522/7976758

Answer (score 2):

In my case the bench command is found here:

```
  frappe@ubuntu:~/frappe-bench$ whereis bench
  bench: /usr/local/bin/bench
```

with /usr/local/bin on my PATH:

```
frappe@ubuntu:~/frappe-bench$ echo $PATH
/home/frappe/bin:/home/frappe/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

To add /usr/local/bin (in the case where it is missing from PATH) just add it your .bashrc file:

PATH=$PATH:~/usr/local/bin/

Then restart the shell using
exec bash

Note that bench commands must be run from the frappe-bench directory (that you specified)

Answer (score 1):

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

worked for me after following the [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Installing Frappe on Linux](https://github.com/frappe/frappe/wiki/The-Hitchhiker%27s-Guide-to-Installing-Frappe-on-Linux).
I started getting the error when I logged back several days after successful installation.

Answer (score 0):

It can be the PATH issue. While installing, in logs it used to give some location that needs to bhi included in PATH. Please check the installation logs.

Answer (score 0):

frappe-bench is also available on PyPI.
Try to install it using:

> pip install frappe-bench

and then execute your command:

> bench init frappe-bench && cd frappe-bench

Note:
You might have to use sudo pip install frappe-bench command in order to install frappe-bench in the root user environment.

Answer (score 0):

After execute this:

```
pip install --user -e bench-repo
```

Close that terminal and open a new one, `bench` will be working now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).