# pip installed pylint cannot be found

Tags: macos, pip, atom-editor, pylint

There's a lot of questions around this, so it might be a duplicate, but I can't find a solution, so here goes..

I want to use pylint with atom. If I use the recommended `pip install --user pylint` it seems to work but atom can't find and neither can I; `which pylint` and `whereis pylint`return nothing. The same thing goes if I use `pip3`.

If I go against wisdom and use `sudo pip install pylint` it *is* found but now I get a different error with atom: `unable to determine environment`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-bash: doc2dash: command not found in OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271232/bash-doc2dash-command-not-found-in-os-x-mavericks)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524522/7976758

Comment: Is this the same as the linter-pylint plugin for Atom?

Comment: @jmh If you mean if this resolved my other question about getting linter-pylint to work then no

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956359/zsh-command-not-found-flake8-but-flake8-is-installed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `which pylint` does not find the executable but the package is installed, it is not in your `PATH`. Uninstall `pylint` you have installed with `sudo` and reinstall it as user, now run

```
$ PATH=$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH which pylint
```

It should be found now. After you have verified `pylint` executable is accessible, edit your `.bash_profile` and add the two lines at the bottom:

```sh
PATH="${HOME}/Library/Python/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Answer (score 14):

I have met exactly the same issue as you. Pylint is installed via `pip install --user pylint` since pip is managed by the system administrator and I have no permission to install packages in the system Python package directory.

The reason `pylint` is not found is just that you haven't added the folder where pylint is installed to the system PATH. The output of `pip show --files pylint` has something like the following:

```
Location: /home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: mccabe, astroid, isort
Required-by: 
Files:
  ../../../bin/epylint
  ../../../bin/pylint
  ../../../bin/pyreverse
  ../../../bin/symilar
```

So pylint is installed in `$HOME/.local/bin`, you should add this folder to PATH:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
```

After that, you should be able to use pylint normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `poetry`, use

```
 poetry run pylint --recursive=y .
```

with pylint-django

```
poetry run pylint --recursive=y --load-plugins pylint_django .
```